# TableViewCellの取得にて、error: 'xxx' has no member named 'yyy'エラー

Tags: swift

下記のコードにて、APIの検索結果内容として[trackName]と[artistName]を記述したのですが、「as? String」のコード記述で「error: 'xxx' has no member named 'yyy'」オブジェクトxxxのはyyyのというメンバーが存在しないというエラーが生じます。

仮定

asを用いた記述が現在の仕様と合致していないことが問題だと考えています。
googleで探してみたのですが、正しい仕様を見つけることができないため質問致します。

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListCell
    if let result = results?[indexPath.row] {
        if let artworkUrl = result["artworkUrl100"] as? String {
            cell.artworkImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: artworkUrl))
        } else {
            cell.artworkImageView.image = nil
        }//ここから
        cell.trackLabel.text = result["trackName"] as? String
        cell.artistLabel.text = result["artistName"] as? String
    }    //ここまででエラーが生じています。
    return cell
}
```

Comment: ListCellに`trackLabel`と`artistLabel`はありますか？

Comment: 存在します。

aritstLabelをcusutomクラスでひも付けたのですが、
「artsitLabel」がメンバーではないとエラーが生じています。

URL
http://qiita.com/kenchan1837/items/a9e1de18c7eab75c4145#%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E7%94%BB%E9%9D%A2%E3%81%AB%E9%81%B7%E7%A7%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A9%A6%E8%81%B4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

を参考にしております。

Comment: 文法上のエラーが生じていると考えますが、対処法が見当たらず今回質問致しました。

Comment: 単純なスペルミスという可能性はありませんか？ex.「artsitLabel」→「artistLabel」

Comment: 1 スペルミスではなかったです。

今回はありがとうございました。

Comment: 「解決しました！！」だけではなく、原因と対処を書いてください。（マイナス評価をつけてる人も、なぜマイナス評価なのか、コメントするべきだと、私は思うんですけどね）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

artistNameをcustomクラスに設定していたのですが、正しく設定されていないためにエラーが生じていました。

再度設定しなおしたらエラーが無くなりました。

---

*質問より転記*